# L'utilisation du pronom « celui »

Tags: pronoms, démonstratifs

Je parlais de sport avec un ami français quand j'ai dit la phrase suivante

> Je ne connais pas ce sport mais je vais lire quelque chose sur celui ce soir.

J'ai utilisé **celui** dans la phrase, il a compris ce que j'ai voulu dire et la conversation a continué mais j'ai commencé à me demander si **celui** est approprié pour ce cas.

Maintenant je pense que **lui** est plus approprié:

> Je ne connais pas ce sport mais je vais lire quelque chose sur lui ce soir.

Quel exemple semble le plus naturel aux francophones ? Pourquoi ?

---

**UPDATE:**

J'ai lu la réponse au-dessous mais je ne suis par sûr de comprendre comment utiliser les pronoms correctement.

Ce matin, j'ai parlé avec mon ami français de nouveau. J'ai essayé de lui expliquer la différence entre Londres (London) et la ville de Londres (City of London). Après la conversation, j'ai écrit deux phrases que j'avais dit et je veux écouter votre feedback sur eux:

> La ville de Londres est comme un pays indépendant dans l'Angleterre, **celle-ci** qui est un pays dans un pays.

J'ai aussi dit:

> Il y a 2000 ans, les romains ont envahi la grande-Bretagne et ils ont fondé 'Londinium'. Ils ont construit un mur autour de la ville et **celui** est la raison pour laquelle la ville existe aujourd'hui.

Est-ce que ces phrases sont correctes ?

Comment: ... un mur autour de la ville et **celui-ci** est la raison ... ; on peut remplacer *et celui[-ci]* par *qui*

Comment: Oui, c'est vrai, mais malgré l'utilisation n'est pas idiomatique (c'est à dire, il ne semble pas naturel), est-ce que l'utilisation est correct grammaticalement ?

Comment: *celui-ci* est correct, mais il est plus courant d'utiliser *celui-là* qui renvoie à ce qui a été exprimé avant *celui-ci* ; en revanche *celui-ci ...* insiste plus sur ce qui va suivre que *qui ...*, suite logique d'une phrase.

Answer (score 4):

La phrase idiomatique serait

> Je ne connais pas **ce** sport mais je vais lire quelque chose **dessus** ce soir.

En fait, même si cette phrase est correcte et idiomatique, spontanément, je dirais plutôt « je vais lire quelque chose à ce sujet », ou éventuellement « à son sujet ».

*Celui* (et les autres formes du même mot : *celle*, *ceux*, *celles*) désigne un élément d'un ensemble. Le mot est forcément suivi d'un complément qui précise de quel élément il s'agit.

> Je ne connais rien aux sports, je vais lire quelque chose sur celui dont tu as parlé.
>   Je ne connais rien aux sports, je vais lire quelque chose sur celui auquel vous êtes en train de jouer.

Le complément peut être autre chose qu'une subordonnée relative. En particulier, *celui de …* est fréquent pour désigner un type d'élément plutôt qu'un élément particulier.

> […] ce couvert est celui de l'ami qui vient et s'en va, ce n'est plus celui d'un maître du logis […]. (Colette, *La Naissance du jour* ; via le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/celui))

On peut même utiliser une tournure pronominale lorsque l'élément est désigné par référence à une mention précédente : on utilise *celui-ci*, *celui-là* (et *celle-ci*, *celle-là*, etc.) pour les éléments d'un ensemble donné par le contexte, de manière parallèle à *cet objet-ci*, cet objet-là* lorsqu'on veut préciser explicitement la catégorie et à *ceci*, *cela* lorsque l'objet est implicite.

Pour en revenir à ta phrase, on dirait « sur ce sport ». Si on veut rendre l'objet implicite, la construction devient « sur cela ». Mais « sur cela » n'est pas idiomatique, on utilise l'adverbe *dessus* à la place (ainsi qu'à la place de « sur ceci »). De même, on dit *dessous* à la place de « sous ceci » ou « sous cela », et (souvent) *à côté* à la place de « à côté de ceci/cela ».

La famille des pronoms démonstratifs est un des rares cas où le français fait une distinction animé/inanimé : *sur cet objet* = *<strike>sur ceci</strike> = *dessus*, mais *sur cette personne* = *sur elle*.

Comment: Est-il donc 100% correct de dire "dessus" à la place de "sur cela" même si le "sur" s'utilise au sens figuré ? Dans ce cas, "sur" veut dire "à propos de". Vu que "dessus" s'agit de l'emplacement de quelque chose, a-t-il du sens de l'utiliser de cette manière ? Je pense que l'emploie de "sur" dans cet example est un anglicisme (mais j'utilise le faut preposition tout le temps, donc j'ai tort peut-être).

Comment: @bronxbomber92 [sur](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sur) IV.C.2, [dessus](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dessus) II.B. Je ne vois pas ce que ça aurait d'un anglicisme, même si je préfère effectivement « au sujet de ».

Comment: « Lire quelque chose là-dessus ».

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Hmmm. Bof. Tu as un ngram ?